# Adding a new button -overlapping WXpython

Tags: wxpython

Im trying to create a panel and trying to add few buttons inside the panel but for somereason only the "ADD" button is displaying,

```
import wx


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent, id, pos,size, style):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id,pos,size,style)
        self.BackgroundColour = 'RED'
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox1.Add(wx.Button(self,label="Add"),flag=wx.LEFT)      
        #hbox1.Add((-1,10))
        hbox1.Add(wx.Button(self,label="Update"),flag=wx.RIGHT)
        #hbox1.Add(wx.Button(self,label="Delete"),flag=wx.LEFT, border=20)
        #hbox1.Add(wx.Button(self,label="Add"),flag=wx.LEFT, border=20)
        #hbox1.Add(wx.Button(self,label="Update"),flag=wx.LEFT, border=20)
        #hbox1.Add(wx.Button(self,label="Delete"),flag=wx.LEFT, border=20)


class MyTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style):
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style)



class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(700, 700))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        tID = wx.NewId()
        self.tree = MyTreeCtrl(panel,tID,wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
        tID = wx.NewId()
        self.lefthandpanel = MyPanel(panel,tID,wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
        vbox.Add(self.tree, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        vbox.Add(self.lefthandpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        isz = (16,16)
        il = wx.ImageList(isz[0], isz[1])
        fldridx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FOLDER,      wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fldropenidx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,   wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fileidx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE, wx.ART_OTHER, isz))


        self.tree.SetImageList(il)
        self.il = il

        # NOTE:  For some reason tree items have to have a data object in
        #        order to be sorted.  Since our compare just uses the labels
        #        we don't need any real data, so we'll just use None below for
        #        the item data.

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")
        self.tree.SetPyData(self.root, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)


        for x in range(15):
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Item %d" % x)
            self.tree.SetPyData(child, None)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

            for y in range(5):
                last = self.tree.AppendItem(child, "item %d-%s" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y)))
                self.tree.SetPyData(last, None)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

                for z in range(5):
                    item = self.tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d-%s-%d" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y), z))
                    self.tree.SetPyData(item, None)
                    self.tree.SetItemImage(item, fileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                    #self.tree.SetItemImage(item, smileidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected)

        print self.tree
        self.Centre()
        self.Show() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        Example(None,title="Border")
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `self.SetSizer(hbox1)` after adding the buttons in `MyPanel` constructor. This way you tell the panel to use the layout.